# Center the Icon of RadioButton in RadioGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

I am trying to center the Button of a RadioButton. None of the already answered questions here fixed my problem.

[image]

**My conditions:**

- the effect of a RadioGroup
- the default RadioButton Icon
- I don't want to set text to the RadioButtons
- the ButtonIcon should be centered (like the position of A1, A2, A3)

I tried different settings but nothing worked for me.

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RadioGroup>
```

**EDIT**: Using Placeholder-RadioButtons is not an option. In this case I would need 9 RadioButtons, but in the end this layout will be created programmatically and the amount of RadioButtons could be bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="A1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="A2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="A3" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/myRadioGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_radio_button_checked_black_24dp"
            android:tag="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp" />

    </RadioGroup>


</LinearLayout>
```

> Activity code

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RadioGroup myRadioGroup;
    RadioButton radioButton,radioButton2,radioButton3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);


        myRadioGroup = findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup);
        radioButton = findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        radioButton2 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        radioButton3 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);


        myRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                if(checkedId==R.id.radioButton){
                    radioButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.ic_radio_button_checked_black_24dp,0,0);

                    radioButton3.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp,0,0);
                    radioButton2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp,0,0);

                }else if(checkedId==R.id.radioButton2){
                    radioButton2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.ic_radio_button_checked_black_24dp,0,0);

                    radioButton3.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp,0,0);
                    radioButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp,0,0);

                }else if(checkedId==R.id.radioButton3){
                    radioButton3.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.ic_radio_button_checked_black_24dp,0,0);

                    radioButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp,0,0);
                    radioButton2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp,0,0);
                }
            }
        });
    }


}
```

> ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM12,20c-4.42,0 -8,-3.58 -8,-8s3.58,-8 8,-8 8,3.58 8,8 -3.58,8 -8,8z"/>
</vector>
```

> ic_radio_button_checked_black_24dp

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,7c-2.76,0 -5,2.24 -5,5s2.24,5 5,5 5,-2.24 5,-5 -2.24,-5 -5,-5zM12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM12,20c-4.42,0 -8,-3.58 -8,-8s3.58,-8 8,-8 8,3.58 8,8 -3.58,8 -8,8z"/>
</vector>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: if I am using android:drawableTop, the button is no more centered vertical

Comment: @K.Dexter happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

Leave your radio buttons as `wrap_content` and then add empty views to fill in all the extra space.  This should center them all.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but as i mentioned, i do not want to use placeholders. A View or a RadioButton makes no difference for me :)